# What happened to the water processors in Oblivion?

Tags: oblivion

I know how the Tom Cruise movie Oblivion ends.

> Jack and Malcolm destroy the Tet mother ship

But what happens to the water processors after?

> Do they shut down and fall into the ocean? Are they still functioning?

No mention is made at the end of the movie. Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Oblivion.html) is explicit on the issue. The "water processors" you've described are referred to by a different name:

**Much earlier**

> Jack shifts the Bubbleship, **in the distance a series of
>   RESOURCE-GATHERERS on the horizon. Essentially titanic vacuums,
>   sucking up the oceans.**

**After the explosion there was an unfilmed sequence:**

> EXT. VARIOUS LANDSCAPES - CONTINUOUS :
>
> DRONES fall from the sky, powerless... **A RESOURCE GATHERER YAWS,
>   losing power, and falls ponderously into what remains of the sea...**

Answer (score 1):

I believe when the Tet pyramid was nuked, all the water processors, like all the drones, simply powered down and fell where ever they were.

Comment: You're correct but it would have been better to offer some evidence to back up your assertion.